# Speeding/traffic ticket

Tags: single-word-requests

Bileto ne ŝajnas ĝusta en tiu senco, mi trovis "monpuno," kaj tio havas sencon. Ĉu estas alia vorto aŭ ĉu vi uzas tiun? En mia vortaro de Benson mi ne trovis tradukon. Kaj kiel oni klarigas kia ĝi estas? Mi ricevis veturigadan monpunon?

Comment: It is a good question. I created a wiki in the hopes that the Esperanto community can create more accurate words and phrases associated with Traffic Violations. https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trafika_Malobservo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Monpuno* means a fine.

I say *punbileto* for this. I don't normally like to quote tatoeba, but from this link it seems that I'm not the only one to say *punbileto*.

http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/1755364

Comment: According to ReVo, a Bileto is some sort of right of passage or entrance. It is like a voucher. I am actually stumped on this one. Maybe Monpuno is a the best option.

Comment: @Lumo5 It works the same in English, doesn't it? *pun-*, so to say, converts a theatre ticket to a traffic ticket.

Comment: ReVo is almost never the most accurate authority on usage.  

A "bileto" is a slip of paper with something written on it.